# Where did the Chrome viewport dimensions go?

Tags: google-chrome

Up until at least last week, Chrome had this nifty feature where, if Developer Tools was open and you drag to resize the window, the current viewport dimensions appear in the top right corner.

(For reference, see the image below, where the big green arrow is pointing, borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204528/chrome-developer-tools-window-dimensions-are-inconsistent).)

I can't get this very useful behavior to happen anymore.  I resize and there's no dimension box.

Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing?  Or a keyboard shortcut that inadvertently toggled this off?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a flag to switch it back on - but if you select the 'body' element from the source, you can read it from the render size box.

You're right though, it was very handy. I'll be looking for a way to bring it back - but there really are a lot of oddly named flags to scroll through.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest version of Chrome and the functionality is still there, though maybe a little differently. Here is a screenshot with pointers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has apparently returned to recent versions of Chrome. Working as of 2016-07-12.